# how to make my sed command work in GNU works in BSD

Tags: ssh, sed, gnu, bsd

I have a block content in my ~/.ssh/config. begin with a line '# BEGIN AUTO GENERATED CONTENT' and end with a line '# END AUTO GENERATED CONTENT'

I have a command replacing content between this two lines, with the content reading from a file named 'config'

```
sed -i -ne '/# BEGIN AUTO GENERATED CONTENT/ {p; r config' -e ':a; n; /# END AUTO GENERATED CONTENT/ {p; b}; ba}; p' ~/.ssh/config
```

it works well in ubuntu, but it cannot work in my mac which use bsd sed. it gave out this error message:

```
sed: 1: "/# BEGIN AUTO GENERATED ...": unexpected EOF (pending }'s)
```

I need to correct this command to work in bsd. not using gsed in mac

Comment: I suggest to [edit] the question and add an explanation what your `sed` script is supposed to do and show the (relevant) contents of `~/.ssh/config`.

Comment: have you considered dropping sed and writing it in something more portable, awk perhaps?

Comment: Why do you have two separate scripts `-e '...'` with unbalanced braces? Can you combine this to one script? Maybe GNU sed somehow combines all to one script while other implementations handle them separately.

Comment: You may want to reword the question title - - it is the opposite of what you require.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, since you are on a Mac, a lone `-i` option won't work. You need to supply a value to it, in your case an empty one.

Secondly, it's ok to change the `p;b` pair to `p;d` in your case since the `-n` switch is in effect. The branch `b` command does not gel well with the closing braces in older `seds` since.

```
$ sed -i '' -ne '/# BEGIN AUTO GENERATED CONTENT/{' -e 'p;r config' -e ':a;n' -e '/# END AUTO GENERATED CONTENT/{' -e 'p;d' -e '}' -e 'ba' -e '}' -e 'p' ~/.ssh/config
```

Unless this is a use-and-throw kinda stuff, it's best to rewrite it in a file, and then invoke as:

```
$ sed -i '' -nf ./code ~/.ssh/config

$ cat ./code
   /# BEGIN AUTO GENERATED CONTENT/{
      p
      r config
      :loop
         n
         /# END AUTO GENERATED CONTENT/{
            p
            d
         }
      bloop
   }
   p
```